# How can I make a function to filter my names into an array list?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to make a filter name with an array list but it does not go any way. Can any of you help me?

This is my private project I'm working on

I want to filter out the names when typing in the input file

```
// List of Names
myList = ["A","B","C","D",];
// declare Var
var ul, li, sortMyNames, input, inputValue;

function getNames() {
    // FUNCTION TO SORT NAMES IN A LIST
    sortMyNames = sortNames();
    // GET INPUT
    getInpValue = getInputValue();

    // GET UL
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");

    for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
        // CREATE LIST ITEM
        li = document.createElement("li");
        // SET ITS CONTENTS
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(myList[i][0]));

        txtValue = li.textContent || li.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(inputValue) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }

        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
    return ul;
}

function getInputVaule() {
    // GET INPUT
    input = document.getElementById("filter-input");
    //GET THE VALUE FROM INPUT
    inputValue = input.value.toUpperCase();
    console.log(inputValue);
}

function sortNames() {
    myList.sort();
}
```

Comment: Can you describe the actual problem you're having? Your `getNames` function returns a `<ul>` but no code shown calls it. Are you handling the return value properly?

Comment: You're also setting a variable (`sortMyNames`) to the result of a function (`sortNames`) that does not return anything, so it will always be `undefined`, although it doesn't appear to be the cause of your problem since you never use that variable.

Answer (score 0):

One problem appears to be that you are constantly adding new `<li>` elements to the `<ul>`, but are never clearing the `<ul>` or removing any list items from it.

Comment: hello @ devios1.
I looked over w3schools. There the code is written without an array, but names with A tag and Li are inserted. I want to create a filter name that will filter the name that I enter into the input. and when I get started, I only add a new Li element to UL.. Could you help me :)